# BackboneJS - How to create a submenu

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

How do I create a submenu in Backbone? I have a main router and main navigationmenu and i want to add a submenu on for example the third page, with addiotional 3-4 anchors.

how do I approach this? Do i have to create some additional routers and "import/load" them in the specific view?

Answer (score 0):

On the views side, you'd handle the submenu view in your *third page* view.

About the routes, if they're related to your third page, then try nested urls:

```
routes: {
  "page/3": "thirdPageHome",
  "page/3/{subPage}": "thirdPageSub"
}
```

Then in `thirdPageSub`, you'd resolve the sub path, and from there I'd dispatch the call to another router method:

```
Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "page/3": "thirdPageHome",
    "page/3/{subPage}": "thirdPageSub"
  },

  thirdPageSub: function( subRoute ) {
    if ( subRoute === "foo" ) return this.thirdPageFoo();
  },

  thirdPageFoo: function() {
    // do your stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: thats great! what if i want the submenu to contain additional 3 anchors, which after clicking they show different content? But yes, maybe your suggestion will lead my way :-)

Comment: At this point it is up to you, ideally reuse layouts and templates and only switch the content (then maybe use the same route handler).